# Help me modify this code to write to database

Tags: php, sql, uploader

So i have to write a form to upload an image to a website...i found the code below, added it to my site, and tested it. Seems to work great. The problem is that theres nowhere in the code that writes to a database....it just uploads the image to a folder and theres no database to keep track of it......I know SQL good enough to get through writing the code....but im not too knowledgeable about where to put the actual sql code.....if i click the GO button to upload the image , the user is taken away fromt this page... so would the sql run?...how can i modify this to add sql code

Any ideas?

Heres the code...any help would be great!

```
<?php
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
define ("MAX_SIZE","500"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file  is an image by checking the extension.
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {
    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
    echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
 }

 ?>

 <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" and use an input type "file" -->
 <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
 <table>
    <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
 </table>   
     </form>
```

Comment: Put your code before `echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";`. However, this code is highly insecure. By "this code" I am referring to the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code within the following block:

```
//If no errors registred, print the success message
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) {
   // do database stuff here...
   echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
}
```

At this point you know the upload was successful. You didn't provide a table schema or SQL flavor. I will assume MySQL. In which case check out [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). The PHP docs have a good example for connecting and running a query.